How to Comply With MIT Licensed SVG In Print
I have found an MIT licensed SVG that I wish to use in print, for instance a business card.
The relevant part of the MIT license:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

My interpretation of this situation is that printing an SVG is not a "copy or substantial portions of the Software", as I am printing the output of rendering the SVG, not the code (XML) of the SVG itself. In fact, I think that even rendering the SVG to a PNG would constitute an output, and I would be the copyright holder of that PNG image under the concept of authorship and "independent creation". I could certainly see arguments against that though.
I am hoping someone has some prior art, or case law, or legal opinions or something for this situation.

This does not answer your question, but I would personally reach out or the author of the SVG for permission to simply omit the license text on your business card. Their selection of MIT suggests an intent to allow very permissive reuse of their work, and did not foresee that the simple requirement to include license text would be tremendously onerous on a business card.

I completely agree with my esteemed colleague.  Anyone who picked the MIT license for an image is likely to be happy to go with, eg, CC BY instead, which would still give them credit but not be unusable on a business card.

Could you say more precisely how you want to reuse this? "For instance a business card" is too vague. For example, if you're using this in a book, then it seems like it would be a pretty simple matter to include the required license text somewhere in the front matter or the back matter. Of course, if your specific question is about a business card, then perhaps that particular use would be more challenging, but maybe it's doable too (e.g. you could package a pack of 100 business cards along with a little fold-up pamphlet on which the required notice is printed).

In copyright law, the PNG is clearly a derivative work of the SVG so the original copyright applies; you don't get to own it by running it through a mechanical translation process, just like you don't get to own copyright in a book by taking a photo of it.
That doesn't necessarily mean that the MIT license applies because as you correctly note it explicitly references "software". Is the PNG software? Maybe. In general, this is why something like the Creative Commons family of licenses are preferred for non-software works.

This doesn't really answer the question of if it's legal or not to use in print.
I can edit out my speculation about if a PNG would be derivative or not, if it distracts from the actual question.

@Beefy_Swain The same observation would apply to a printout, or to any other example format, though. For example, if you were to print out the SVG on paper, and then rescan it in via scanner, apply some filters to remove as much physical coloration distortion as possible, and then apply an algorithm to convert that back into a "new" SVG, it seems like that SVG would still ultimately be a derivative of the original.
